# Angular 2 map.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to added some values to my map. For example I have the following,

My AddressBook class

```
export class AddressBook {
  constructor(
    public social: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>(),

  ) {
  }
}
```

here is what the server is returning,

```
{
 social: {
 twitter: "twitterId",
 facebook: "facebookId",
 linkedIn: "linkedinId",
 pinterest: "pinterestId"
 }
}
```

This is my method to add to my social map

```
this.addressBook.social.set('Google+','GooglePlusId');
```

But I get the following error

```
caused by: this.addressBook.social.set is not a function
```

Here is how i retrieve the data from the server

```
 return this.http.get(this.addressBookURL+address_book_id)
      .map(res => <AddressBook> res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);

this.addressBookService.getAddressBookFromId(address_book_id)
      .subscribe((res) => {
          this.addressBook = res;

        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        });
```

Not sure how to solve this. If anyone can point me the right direction that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: how is your `AddressBook` constructed ? Please, provide the `new AddresseBook(someData)` part.

Comment: here is my AddressBook
`export class AddressBook {
  constructor(
    public social: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>(),
  ) {
  }
}`

Comment: I already know that.... the `new AddresseBook(someData)` part, please !!!!

Comment: I've updated my question to include how I instantiate the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you don't pass the right argument to the AddressBook constructor.
Actually I guess you are doing this:

```
let addressBook= new AdresseBook({
 twitter: "twitterId",
 facebook: "facebookId",
 linkedIn: "linkedinId",
 pinterest: "pinterestId"
 } as any);
```

while you should pass a `Map` Object...

```
let map = new Map();
let obj = {
  twitter: "twitterId",
  facebook: "facebookId",
  linkedIn: "linkedinId",
  pinterest: "pinterestId"
};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  map.set(key, obj[key]);
});
let addressBook = new AdresseBook(map);
```

**Edit:** and I'm right (I'm always right), you cannot expect a plain object to be a Map :

```
 return this.http.get(this.addressBookURL+address_book_id)
      .map(res => <AddressBook> res.json()) //here you are just telling the compiler
                                            // that resp.json() is an AdresseBook, but 
                                            // it's not right, it's a plain Object
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

This should work :

```
 return this.http.get(this.addressBookURL+address_book_id)
      .map(res => {
        let map = new Map();
        let social = res.json().social;
        Object.keys(social).forEach(key => {
          map.set(key, social[key]);
        });
        return new AdresseBook(map);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: My AddressBook class looks like this 
`export class AddressBook {
  constructor(
    public social: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>(),
  ) {
  }
}`
The data is coming from the server. All I am trying to do is add a new item to that map.

Comment: I know how the class looks it is in your question, I don't know how it is instanciated the `new AdressBook(data)` part.

Comment: I've updated my question to include how I instantiate the class. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Thanks dude, you are correct. This has resolved my issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

try to install `@types/core-js` module it contains typescript definitions for all es6 features (Map, Set ...) :

```
npm install @types/core-js --save


you may need to uninstall @types/es6-promise
```

Comment: The project was generated using angular cli, also installing @types/core-js had not effect. Do i need to set it up some how? Thanks

Comment: this is how i am receiving the data `this.addressBookService.getAddressBookFromId(address_book_id)
      .subscribe((res) => {
          this.addressBook = res;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        });`